# create a key- value pair in a for loop using python and update the value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, for-loop

I am new to python and learning the stuff from scratch. One thing I want to do, but couldn't find out how is to create a key-value pair list using the for loop and update just the value. A sample code is:

```
for i in range(0,6)
  #####some code that gives an output integer x.
  print(i,x)
```

The integer x is different for each i.  How do I create a list like {0:x0,1:x1,2:x2,3:x3,4:x4,5:x5}, using the for loop?

Comment: That is not a list, that is a `dict`. Do you want a `list` or a `dict`?

Comment: Is the value `x0` in your example the string literal `'x0'`, or what does `x` represent? Where does it come from?

Comment: @pushkin Presumably from "some code that gives an output integer x"

Comment: I am sorry, I want a dictionary. and x1,x2,,etc are just the different integer value of x through each iteration.

Comment: Why do you want a dictionary? Your data looks like it should be a list.

Comment: i don't think it would matter, considering each key is unique and both lists and dicts are iterable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for [Python Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

```
sample = {}
for i in range(6):
   # some code that gives you x
   sample[i] = x
print(sample)
```

Do note, however, that since your keys are just `0, 1, 2` etc., you may want to just use a list instead:

```
sample = []
for i in range(6):
    # some code that gives you x
    sample.append(x)
print(sample)
```

Note that dictionary access using `sample[key]` will look identical to list access using `sample[index]` since you're just using consecutive numeric keys.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
dic = {}
x = "8"
for i in range(6):
    #calculate x
    dic[i] = int(str(x)+str(i))

print(dic)

{0: 80, 1: 81, 2: 82, 3: 83, 4: 84, 5: 85}
```